What is the or some of the surefire ways to safeguard against Rostazas for sleeping/lesser activity if one is unarmed or lightly armed?
So I have this story about humans getting teleported into a world where everything is so big that a 6 foot man is equivalent to an inch. It should be noted that it is pretty Earthlike in terms of weather and setting besides the size difference.
There is a giant scientist that for whatever reason despises them, so he engineers a bioweapon to hunt them: Rostaza(s)(‘monster’ in the Kotava conlang).
These creatures are largish(for humans), at around 12-14 feet long and 6-8 feet tall, and are humanoidish raptory things, kinda like the Tree Creepers in Primeval. They have enhanced speed, leaping, agility, strength, can climb up walls, and will probably have axolatl level regeneration. They are mostly visual and auditory based hunters, but I imagine smell is important to them as well. They have more abilities, but these are most likely not needed to answer my question. Also, it should be noted that they mass kill like foxes and weasels/ferrets, so humans sticking in groups are not safe in the case of attacks.
Now that I have the info on the world and monsters, let us get to my question: What is the surefire or some of the surefire things one could do to keep themselves safe while asleep/not on the move from Rostazas if one's self is unarmed/lightly armed? Lightly armed in this case means like a small knife or maybe a small revolver with 1 bullet, and not active is not on the move and resting or coming up with plans or whatnot.
Originally I had imagined that some of these people that got brought here eventually realized that sleeping on the tops of, say ketchup bottles, was a good way to stay safe. While this sounds rather clever on paper, realistically, it would not work for a few reasons. First, getting up a table is a monumental feat without gear if it is even possible, let alone a slippery bottle with little to no holds. And second, while the top/lid is probably bigger than most people's beds, it is also alot higher than them too, and a fall would prove fatal. Also, since Rostazas can climb tables, they would have little trouble getting to them. Hopefully you guys have some better ideas.

(a) The [help/dont-ask] prohibits providing your own answers and expecting more. (b) The [help/on-topic] discourages brainstorming and prohibits questions about individual and organization choices. (c) And this question is too story-based as any answer depends entirely on the circumstances of your story (most questions asking for the "best" of anything are entirely circumstantial). What resources are available? What are the skills and talents of the characters? What knowledge do they have of the world, their situation, and the beast? What are their personalities and attitudes? Etc. ...

... So, VTC:Too Story-Based. I'll retract the vote if you [edit] your question to resolve these issues. (And please don't forget the [help/on-topic] specifically states we're here to help you  build your world, not tell your story.)

How is it too story based? @JBH

Questions asking how characters can overcome a situation are story-based because you're asking about what decisions they might make, which always depends on the circumstances of the story (not the world). Can you rewrite this question to remove any reference to character decisions? Further, asking for "best" (or any superlative) is always a problem because an action or applicable tool may be best based on the one set of story circumstances and not when applied to another. You need to remove your story from the question.

IDK if I can remove the 'character decisions' from it without voiding the answer I got but I can reword some of it. @JBH

I reworded the title and question.@JBH

All you did was change superlatives. None of the three problems have been resolved.

How do I edit it to remove the story bits? Please give me an example. Not trying to be difficult? @JBH

Personally, Conan, I don't think this question can be saved. You're asking for help writing your story - we don't do that. We'll help you design the creatures. We'll help you design weapons. We'll help you define basic cultures. But the moment you ask, "how do my characters defeat my monster?" you've asked an illegal question. We don't help you write your story. One of the better tests is to ask yourself, "how would I judge a single best answer?" If you can't answer that (or don't want to), you're asking your question in the wrong place.

Don't get tall - get small!
Compare your humans and the Rostanzas to a rat defending itself from a cat. The rat doesn't look for shelter via height, cause cats can climb just as well if not better than a rat can. Instead, rats burrow, creating nests with access points too small for the cat to fit through, and ideally in material too tough to dig out (such as a crevice between rocks, or between wooden building materials in a house). As long as the rat's in their hidey hole, they're safe, and even if the cat is persistent (most aren't; predators tend to look for targets of opportunity) the rat can stockpile supplies to wait out a siege.
Your humans appear to have the advantage of at least some technology, and as humans they're capable of sentient thought and advanced communication. As long as Rostazas can't/won't coordinate long-term, the natural defensive strategy for humans looking for a safe space would be not just to dig, but to tunnel, creating a network of habitable rooms connected by tunnels too narrow for a Rostaza to fit through (the dimensions you describe for the Rostaza seem to have just enough difference that a tunnel a human could commando-crawl through would be too narrow for a Rostaza). That way, even if a Rostaza somehow dug or otherwise broke into one chamber, the rest of the network is safe.

Guerrilla warfare Vietcong style. I like it.
